# Primary Category doesn't display inside Super Search results

Tags: solspace, supersearch, primary-category

Inside `{exp:super_search:results}` I cannot get a Primary Category to display. Normally I would use `{exp:primary_category}{primary_category_name}{/exp:primary_category}` inside `{exp:channel:entries}`. That works fine but the same thing side Super Search results doesn't work.

Is there something special I have to do to display Primary Category? Strange that it wouldn't work in Super Search since they are both Solspace add-ons!

Comment: EE, Super Search, and Primary Category versions, as well as full template code, please :) Also, try using `entry_id=""` with `{exp:primary_category}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `entry_id="{entry_id}"` to `{exp:primary_category}` fixed it. This is not required in channel:entries but is required in Super Search results.